# Image Upload Not working when i take picture

Tags: angularjs

I am using ng-file-upload and ng-img-crop (http://jsfiddle.net/xxo3sk41/1/)  plugin for uploading image and crop, it is working fine in mobile when I choose picture from galary and its not working when i took picture from my iPhone Camera and upload it is not working.

In AngularJS I am using below code

```
 $scope.$watch("picFile", function(value) {
     if (value) {
         var photoSize = (value.size/1000000) <= 2 ;
         var photoext = !(validPhoto(value.name));
         if (!photoSize && !photoext) {
             $scope.showPPicFlag = false;
             angular.element('.helpmesspic').find('span')[0].style.color = "red";
             angular.element('.helpmesspic').find('span')[1].style.color = "red";
             angular.element('.uploadPhoto').prop('disabled', true);
          } else if (!photoSize) {
              $scope.showPPicFlag = false;
              angular.element('.helpmesspic').find('span')[0].style.color = "red";
              angular.element('.uploadPhoto').prop('disabled', true);
          } else if ( !photoext) {
              $scope.showPPicFlag = false;
              angular.element('.helpmesspic').find('span')[1].style.color = "red";
              angular.element('.uploadPhoto').prop('disabled', true);
          } else {
              $scope.showPPicFlag = true;
              angular.element('.uploadPhoto').prop('disabled', false);
          }
    }
}, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add ngf-capture directive and set it's value to 'camera' or 'other'

```
...
<div>Crop Image and Upload</div>
    <button ngf-select ngf-capture="'camera'" ng-model="picFile" accept="image/*">
        Select Picture</button>
    <div ngf-drop ng-model="picFile" ngf-capture="'camera'"  ngf-pattern="image/*" class="cropArea">
...
```